# Rails & JBuilder - Data type of DECIMAL(10,2) output as a string

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm having trouble with a Rails app that I inherited and I have no experience with Rails. It uses JBuilder to return a JSON response from a MySQL database. I updated the app to add a couple of new columns to the database, of type `DECIMAL(10,2)`. The problem is, when I request the JSON, the value is returned as a string. If I use `DECIMAL(10,0)` then it's returned as a number. Is there a way to force JBuilder to return a number? The relevant parameter is game_score in the following example.

The relevant part of the controller:

```
  # GET /game
  # GET /game.json
  def index
    if params[:since]
      since_datetime = Time.parse(params[:since])
      @game = current_user.game.where(["updated_at >= ? and deleted is not true",  since_datetime])
    else
      @game = current_user.game.where('deleted is not true')
    end

  end
```

the index.json.jbuilder file:

```
json.array!(@game) do |game|
   json.extract! game, :id, :game_date, :game_score, :game_location, :game_team, :game_referee
   json.url game_url(game, format: :json)
end
```

JSON when MySQL data type is `DECIMAL(10,2)`:

```
[{"id":4814,"game_date":"2014-09-10T15:51:00.000Z","game_score":"1.55","game_location":null,"game_team":"Team 1","game_referee":null, "url":"http://[ip]/game/4814.json"}]
```

JSON when MySQL data type is `DECIMAL(10,0)`:

```
[{"id":4814,"game_date":"2014-09-10T15:51:00.000Z","game_score":1,"game_location":null,"game_team":"Team 1","game_referee":null, "url":"http://[ip]/game/4814.json"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest way is write this field manually, like:

```
json.game_score game.game_score.to_f
```